# Кривой запрос к БД

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с запросом к БД?  тут кривовато, конечно, ну как могу пока:). В общем проблема в том, что данные писаться не хотят. Если пользователь не зашел - надо чтобы 0 в id ставился, или что угодно.. (если пользователь авторизирован - там легче, просто получать id через сессию, а как тут.. даже идей нет..). Я понятия не имею что ставить, если честно. Время - текущее, tags_id - получается из таблицы. Вообще это должно быть нес[image: введите сюда описание изображения]колько значений, но  type = "radio" почему-то игнорирутся.. Я новичок. Совсем, если что. Если кто-то сможет написать пример, чтобы я могла увидеть, как это правильно - было бы очень здорово. Потому что у меня не выходит. Я уже не знаю, как еще сделать..

```
    <?php 
     if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>

  <?php
    $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if (isset($_POST["discription"]))
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `quote` (`users_id `, `tags_id`, `author`, `discription`, `data`) VALUES (NULL, '{$_POST['tags_id']}', '{$_POST['author']}', '{$_POST['discription']}', $data')";
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    
        if ($sql)
        {
            echo '<h2>Данные добавлены!</h2>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<h2>Произошла ошибка. Данные не записаны.</h2>';
        }                
    }
    ?>
    
        <!-- Триггер/Открыть модальный -->
        <button id="myBtn">Открыть</button>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <!-- Модальный -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    
        <!-- Модальное содержание -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Создание цитаты</p>
            <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Жанр:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="author"/>
            </div>
            <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Цитата:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                <textarea name="discription" class="form-control" id="shortdescription" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Теги:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">                  
            <select class="form-control" type = "radio" name="tags_id">
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT `id`, `Name` FROM `tags`');
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                echo "\t\t<option value=\"{$result['id']}\">{$result['Name']}</option>\n";
                }
            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Сохранить" name="ok" class = "l"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Так... как select связан с radio? Какая проблема с запросом SQL?

Comment: Вот тут и кроется проблема кажется, ахахах. Надо чтобы можно было множественный выбор (чтоб все значения в бд были представлены, поэтому там select) сделать, чтобы несколько значений (до 3 включительно) записывалось в 1 ячейку в бд. т.е. 1 цитата несколько тегов. А с запросом проблема в том - что он не добавляет в бд. Я не понимаю, что с ним не так..

Comment: Я думаю может проблема в том, что в бд поле data - типа datatime и лучше слать его просто varchar, чтобы не было проблем? или все оставить как есть, но тогда в чем проблема - я не могу понять..

Comment: Что то вы смешали в одну кучу мух с котлетам. Подебажте совой PHP код, посмотрите, какая ошибка возвращается из БД. Мне как минимум не нравятся 2 вещи - `, $data')` Тут либо не хватает кавычки, либо она лишняя. и вот это вот `'{$_POST['tags_id']}'` Соберите в строку ваш запрос sql и посмотрите на его корректность

Comment: почему вам не нравится это строчка? '{$_POST['tags_id']}'. я получаю id тега, который пользователь выбирает через select.

Насчет мух, хахах.. Да, я правда стараюсь сделать все лучше, но получается как всегда:) :(

Comment: Вот как выглядит запрос на вставку: INSERT INTO `quote` (`users_id `, `tags_id`, `author`, `discription`, `data`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'er', 'er', 2022-09-30 11:31:45). Вроде.. не плохо? ту кавычку я убрала, она была лишняя. забыла уубрать ее вначале. Может вся проблема и вправду в том, что в бд поле data - типа datatime и лучше слать его просто varchar? Или проблема точно не в этом?

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть дату в кавычки. Работа с датами в БД самая сложная на мой взгляд. И гадать лучше не на кофейной гуще а на ошибках, которые вам возвращает БД :)

Comment: Мм.. Да, вы правы. Однако это не помогло:(( теперь он возвращает то же самое, но в кавычках:))

Comment: Возьмите свой sql И попробуйте выполнить напрямую в БД. Без ошибки помочь сложно

Comment: А, ну, в общем, я догадывалась.. вот ответ бд: #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'users_id ' в 'field list'

Вот и возникает вопрос, что тогда писать в этот столбец, если неизвестно id пользователя тк он не зарегистрирован? Я думала null поможет с этим, но увы. Что тогда писать туда? Возможно вы знаете..

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно: Неизвестный столбец 'users_id ' в 'field list'

Comment: Так. Да. Простите за тугодумство мое.. хахах.. Я знаю, что такого столбца там нет, надо же чтобы он его.. записал? Поэтому я и спрашиваю, что писать вместо null значения, если неизвестно id пользователя. Его нет в таблице, это ясно, но что писать в таком случае? Или так сделать нельзя и только если id конкретного пользователя передается? Вот в чем вопрос..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139539/discussion-between-neko-and-swad).